# Error : "The URL '/index.html' did not match any routes in your application"

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Im trying to use ember build to build and deploy an ember-cli app. But Im running into an error when the page loads:

> Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/index.html' did not match any routes in your application
>       at new Error (native)
>       at Error.EmberError (file:///Users/me/Work/lunch-picker/dist/assets/vendor.js:26504:23)
>       at Object.Ember.assert (file:///Users/me/Work/lunch-picker/dist/assets/vendor.js:16791:15)
>       at file:///Users/me/Work/lunch-picker/dist/assets/vendor.js:37949:17
>       at tryCatch (file:///Users/me/Work/lunch-picker/dist/assets/vendor.js:58376:20)
>       at invokeCallback (file:///Users/me/Work/lunch-picker/dist/assets/vendor.js:58385:21)
>       at publish (file:///Users/me/Work/lunch-picker/dist/assets/vendor.js:58363:17)
>       at publishRejection (file:///Users/me/Work/lunch-picker/dist/assets/vendor.js:58314:9)
>       at file:///Users/me/Work/lunch-picker/dist/assets/vendor.js:41939:9

This is what my router.js looks like

```
this.resource('lunches', { path: '/'}, function(){
  this.route('unserved');
  this.route('served');
});
this.route('login');
```

I have no problems using ember serve, which shows me this as the next debug log in the console:

> route:application .......................................... lunch-picker/application/route

I'm using ember-cli 0.0.39; and in config/environment.js

> baseURL: 'Users/me/Work/lunch-picker/dist/',

and access it in the browser via:

> file:///Users/me/Work/lunch-picker/dist/index.html

Not exactly sure how to debug this, or if someone looking at this has the information they need to help.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you by chance using [history based routing instead of hash based routing](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/)?

Comment: If I'm not wrong you are referring to the location option in the router, which is set at 'auto'. Setting it to 'hash' solves it.

Comment: Are you using IIS? This might help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481543/how-to-run-emberjs-application-in-iis/32620428#32620428](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481543/how-to-run-emberjs-application-in-iis/32620428#32620428)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the location option set to `auto`, your application is likely using history based routing. You can read more about history based routing at the [link I gave in the comments](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/). In short, you probably want to set your location option to `hash` so you don't have to make any server side changes.

Comment: Thank you so much! (for also saving my already much receded hairline)

Comment: Worth noting - https://github.com/nfrasser/ember-router-location-resolver; This is built in post ember 1.5 and up.