# How to run emberJS application in IIS?

Tags: ember.js, iis-7, ember-cli

I have an EmberJS application that is built using Ember CLI.
To deploy my application I used the `ember build --release` command with Ember CLI, and copied the output from the `/dist` folder into the folder that is mapped with IIS.
Everything seems to work fine. The url is updated when you navigate inside the SPA, data is fetched from Web Service etc. BUT if I try to access `localhost/someurl` directly, I get a 404 Not Found error. I'm guessing this is because of the routing in IIS 7, but how can I make this work with Ember routing?

Comment: You need to route everything to the index.html file and have ember handle the url. Modify your webconfig, not sure how you do it with IIS but on apache we use .htaccess

Comment: Alternatively `location: hash` will solve that problem

Comment: After some research add `Request=* page=index.html` to your web.config and it should work, might break your assets link

Comment: I'm doing ember with a .net api backend and I'm having a similar issue, but not sure what I'll do to fix it yet. In development I'm changing the MVC routes to `{*url}` and mapping everything to `~/home/index` which is where I render the ember app, so it doesn't try to find a server controller for anything other than `~/home/index`, but I'm not sure how bad this is. Sure doesn't sound like the way to go.

Comment: No, I do not like that solution either. For now I have just ignored this issue, becuse this website is going to be wrapped inside a phone gap solution.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is old but i found a very nice solution to the problem using the IIS URL Rewrite module (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) which basically mimic's apache's mod_rewrite.

Basically you define the rewrite rules in a web.config you place along side the dist/* files you dropped into an IIS directory and then go to town.

Here is my rewrite rule block in my web.config.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CatchAll For Ember" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you remove the IsDirectory check then it will still use IIS's 404 for bad directories.

This allows you to host ember applications in IIS without using the /#/ technique.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not working with this project or any ember solution right now, so I can not try to make this work for me. That being said, by the look of it I think this  is the best solution if it works :)

Comment: slapping this file in the `dist` folder worked for me! thanks!

Comment: do you need to install url-rewrite for this to work?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to get get this to work on IIS, and similar to the way other route frameworks work in IIS like Sammy.js, is to include a hash in the url like this `http://0.0.0.0:4200/#/your-route/`

In EmberJS, this is achieved by modifying the application router:

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'hash'
});
```

In your case, since you're using ember-cli, you modify the environment.config file:

```
var ENV = {
   ...
   locationType: 'hash'
   ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `ASP.Net WebApi` with `Identity` and I also wanted to avoid returning `index.html` for non-existent files so I did this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="to-ember" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^/?(.+\.[a-z0-9]+$|token$|api/)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```