# ember cli url not working on server with manual return key (versus link-to)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

An ember cli site was deployed onto a server and it works fine. Links via {{link-to}} all work beautifully.

BUT, when a user (me that is) manually enters a url and hits return. then the site is not found.

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

even changing a parameter of a working url (initially navigated to thru link-to)

```
http://site/start/0/length/30
```

and simply backspacing, changing the 30 to 20 and hit return

```
http://site/start/0/length/20
```

its a no go

`localhost:4200` doesn't have this issue.

has anyone observed this vicious behaviour.

i actually need it for a `callback redirect for oauth`. but then noticed than any manually entered urls dont function.

Comment: How are you running it?  That is, it it deployed on a webserver such as nginx or apache, or are you using the built in `ember server`?

Comment: the built-in ember server has no problem. its deployed on a $%#@ winblows machine

Comment: ill point out that the non-cli version used #index.html/start/0/length/30 and functioned no problem. so its appears to be a # function

Comment: or could be a frigging windows server thing since ember server (localhost) worked without a hitch on osx

Comment: so this is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481543/how-to-run-emberjs-application-in-iis

Comment: You don't need to set it to hash, what's the IIS equivalent of an apache `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving this up from any web server that isn't the built in Ember, ie non local server, you need to have a wildcard rule that returns your Ember app's `index.html` file for anything below your websites base url. If you only have your base url return the `index.html` file, then your webserver is confused by the unrecognized url and thinks it has nothing to return. If your rule, though, 
for `baseUrl/*` returns `index.html`, your Ember app will then run the correct route hooks to establish the app context

Comment: thats sounds like a solid speculation. can you point out how to fix that wildcard rule

Comment: It was speculation because at the time you hadn't specified how you were trying to serve it. Im almost positive its this issue. its a server rule. I dont know how you set up rules on a ` $%#@ winblows machine` but wherever you have the the rule set up to return your `index.html` file, make sure it does it for any path that matches your base url with a `*` character

Comment: this appears in ember-cli. "If you have manually set the *locationType* in your environment.js to hash or none you need to update your tests/index.html to have absolute paths (/assets/vendor.css and /testem.js vs the default relative paths)." i'll experiment because i dont want to mess with a ` $%#@ winblows machine`

Comment: your windows machine is resolving the url on refresh. it has no idea how to serve the ember related urls. It thinks there's nothing to serve for `start/0/length/30`. I dont see how you can avoid setting up a wildcard ruleto handle such a case

Comment: isn't it possible to return to the non ember-cli (index.html hashed) option somehow. not to disregard what you are saying but configuring windows is total nonsense.

Comment: but the request always goes to your webserver first. and your webserver will always respond with "I dont know what the hell to do with this filepath". This has nothing to do with Ember cli. This has to do with you hitting refresh, which sends an http GET request to `site/start/0/length/30. Your windows server has to know how to respond to this. It cannot be that hard to configure this, nor is there much of an option around this

Answer (score 0):

It is because your server (IIS?) is trying to access the full path requested by your browser (eg `/start/0/length/30`), and not finding a valid file on disk returns a `404`.

So, you need to configure your web server to proxy/rewrite the requests to the proper location.  Assuming you are deploying your application in your "root" directory, the proper location is `/index.html` (the file ember-cli creates).

Unfortunately, I can't help you with IIS, but I can provide you with the proper configuration for nginx:

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

This says "If the requested URI doesn't exist, instead respond with the /index.html file".

When you are using `ember server` on `localhost:4200` you don't have the same problem because it is automatically doing something similar transparently.

Answer (score 0):

this is a dupe and the question is

[How to run emberJS application in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481543/how-to-run-emberjs-application-in-iis)

the easy answer is set `locationType: hash` in ember-cli's `environment.config` file (copied from accepted answer)

that will introduce a '#' in the url but doesnt require an IIS change.

```
var ENV = {
   ...
   locationType: 'hash'
   ... };
```